# Martingale with bounded increments converge?

Tags: limits, martingales

Prove or disprove the following arguments:

1. There exists a martingale $\left(M_{n}\right)_{n}$ with bounded increments such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} M_{n}=\infty$
2. There exists a martingale $\left(M_{n}\right)_{n}$ with bounded increments such that $\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} M_{n}=\infty$

I am not sure how to to go about dis-proving statement 2 but for statement 1, I was going to use Martingale Convergence Theorem as $M_n$ is uniformly integrable martingale but I am not sure I am heading in the right direction.

Comment: You can't disprove (2), because it's true.

Comment: See page 224 of https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi83NuYk9n3AhUOrHIEHfqsDVcQFnoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1zF2wBS10F7yy1sBYoIHRu. It proves that (1) is false and suggests that (2) is true.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Thank you! I guess I am more lost that I think.

Comment: @Mason Thank you! Will check it and try to decipher